# Mysql Like for alias column

Tags: mysql, alias, sql-like

I would like to search in an alias column with this query:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT `name` FROM agent WHERE agent.`id`=sys_users.`agent_id`) as agentName FROM `sys_users` where agentName like '%company%'
```

but when i execute the query, MySQL tell me:

**Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'agentName' in 'where clause'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a `WHERE` clause (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html)). You need to use `HAVING` instead i.e.

```
SELECT *, 
   (SELECT `name` FROM agent WHERE agent.`id`=sys_users.`agent_id`) as agentName 
   FROM `sys_users` HAVING agentName like '%company%'
```

Since you want to be able to `OR` conditions it is probably better to use a `JOIN` i.e.

```
SELECT *
    FROM sys_users JOIN agent ON agent.id = sys_users.agent_id
    WHERE sys_users.username LIKE '%company%' OR agent.name LIKE '%company%'
```

Note that in this case you will need to be careful of cases where `sys_users` and `agent` have colums with the same name, so it is probably better to explicitly list the columns you want.

Comment: It's OK but i would like to user **WHERE** and **HAVING** simultaneously for example:

`SELECT *, 
   (SELECT `name` FROM agent WHERE agent.`id`=sys_users.`agent_id`) as agentName 
   FROM `sys_users` 
   WHERE username like '%company%'`
   HAVING agentName like '%company%'`

but i would like to search company in username **OR** agentName

Comment: You can put username in the HAVING clause as well i.e. HAVING username LIKE '%company%' OR agentName LIKE '%company%' however this is inefficient (MySQL will not optimise it), so it's probably better to use a JOIN. I will edit my answer.